# Issue With Python and Django timezone format

Tags: python, django, django-views

I recently added in my `settings.py` `USE_TZ = True` to get Celery working on my Django project and now in my other views that use the `datetime.strptime` command, it is adding the `-04:00` since my time zone is `America/New_York`. I don't need the time zone for this field. How do I remove the timezone from this? Here is my code below.

```
new_event.start = datetime.strptime(str(obj.start_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
new_event.end = datetime.strptime(str(obj.end_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose in the variable `my_time_1` is stored the time with a delta of `X_var` hours with respect to the one you wish.

You can cancel the delta "manually" by doing this:

```
X_var = -4 # In your case the delta is equal to -4

from datetime import timedelta    
my_time_1 = my_time_1 + timedelta(hours=X_var)
```

However, this is not very clean, and maybe you should convert a time expressed according to a former timezone into a time expressed according to a latter one.

You could use this custom function:

```
# I copied it from some SO question but can't find which one

import pytz, datetime    

def convert_datetime_timezone(date_and_time_input, tz1, tz2):
    tz1 = pytz.timezone(tz1)
    tz2 = pytz.timezone(tz2)

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_and_time_input,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    dt = tz1.localize(dt)
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz2)
    dt = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt
```

And so, to switch back `my_time_1` from America/New_York to UTC, you can use:

```
my_time_1 = convert_datetime_timezone(my_time_1, America/New_York, UTC)
```

---

What you should do to fix your problem:

substitute:

```
new_event.start = datetime.strptime(str(obj.start_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
new_event.end = datetime.strptime(str(obj.end_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

with:

```
import pytz, datetime    

def convert_datetime_timezone(date_and_time_input, tz1, tz2):
    tz1 = pytz.timezone(tz1)
    tz2 = pytz.timezone(tz2)

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_and_time_input,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    dt = tz1.localize(dt)
    dt = dt.astimezone(tz2)
    dt = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    return dt

adjusted_start_date = convert_datetime_timezone(obj.start_date, America/New_York, UTC)
adjusted_end_date = convert_datetime_timezone(obj.end_date, America/New_York, UTC)

new_event.start = datetime.strptime(str(adjusted_start_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
new_event.end = datetime.strptime(str(adjusted_end_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I appreciate the response , but im very confused on this. Can you use it with my variables up top so i can better understand the logic ?

Comment: If i wanted to keep the TimeZone in there, what would the format be for that  ?

Comment: So this I'm not understanding. I left the timezone rather than removing it. It works on my dev server on sql lite but it doesnt work on my herokuapp production environment. I just added  %z  at the end of :%S %z and i get the following error time data '2020-10-11 01:00:46-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'''

Comment: Take a close look to the datetime you wrote and the format displayed by the error message, they differ of a "-". The format should be  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-%z'''